# Restrict :nth-child results to visible elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, visibility, css-selectors

In jQuery, I want to add a class to all visible elements that are the 5th child or greater, and another class to each element that isn't a 4th child. Previously, I was doing this:

```
$overlay.find('> .container .content .selector').not(':nth-child(4n)').addClass('hasRightMargin');
$overlay.find('> .container .content .selector:nth-child(n+5)').addClass('hasTopMargin');
```

However, now I'm toggling the visibility of the first `.selector`, and `:nth-child` does not take visibility into account, so this does not work as I want, because it's still counting the invisible element:

```
$overlay.find('> .container .content .selector:visible').not(':nth-child(4n)').addClass('hasRightMargin');
$overlay.find('> .container .content .selector:visible:nth-child(n+5)').addClass('hasTopMargin');
```

Is there a way to do what I want in one selector? Or will I have to loop through all `.selector` elements using `each` and filter them there manually?

Comment: So you're trying to select everything other than every 4th visible element on the screen?

Comment: I also think you should change your selector for '5th element or greater' to :gt(4). I find it less confusing, and that should let it work alongside your :visible selector.

Comment: @Evil Yes. And the second line should select all visible elements but the first four.

Comment: It would be cool if the css spec added some way to limit the items.  Ex `:not(#el[display:none]):nth-match(2n)` so that you get the nth items of the first match.  Please not that `:not()` is not yet implemented in the major browsers.

Comment: I mean `:not(#el[display=none]):nth-match(2n)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the trick.

```
$overlay.find('> .container .content .selector:visible:not(:odd:odd)').addClass('hasRightMargin');
$overlay.find('> .container .content .selector:visible:gt(3)').addClass('hasTopMargin');
```

Your primary issue is that nth child selects all elements that are the nth child of their parent, **not** the nth elements in the set. Also, keep in mind that selectors such as :odd,:even,:gt,:lt are 0-indexed. So :odd selects the elements 1,3,5,etc. which are the 2nd,4th,6th elements on the page. And :odd:odd selects every 4th element on the page. Likewise, :gt(3) selects all elements with index of 4 or more, which is the 5th element and beyond.

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EvilAmarant7x/A2DYT/1/) for a jsfiddle that, I think, demonstrates what you were looking for. Note the hidden divs that get passed over.

Comment: NICE! I had never seen `:odd:odd` before. Judging from your jsFiddle, this seems to match my requirements exactly, I will test it at work tomorrow and will accept your answer assuming it works without problems :)

Comment: @Aistina Now, if you had asked how to select every 5th element or something, I would have had no idea other than using a loop.

Comment: @Aistina Actually, I see that .filter() would be what you want for other nth elements. So 

$overlay.find('> .container .content .selector:visible').filter( function (index) { return ((index+1)%4!=0);}).addClass('hasRightMargin');

Would also work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you .find() on visible elements before you apply your :nth-child selector? Maybe something like

```
$overlay.find("> :visible").find('.container .content .selector').not(':nth-child(4n)')...
```

Comment: That's already more or less what I'm doing in line 1 of my example code that doesn't work.